# Spring Boot not recognizing application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure a DynamoDb client with Spring Boot, and placed my endpoints and configuration information in my resources/application.properties file. However, Spring Boot does not seem to pick up these properties. It does pick up the "server.default" key that I have stored in the same file, so it is definitely recognizing the  the file itself.

Here is my application.properties file and the class I'm trying to load properties into (**DynamoDBClientMapper**):

```
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://localhost:8000/
amazon.dynamodb.region=us-west-1
amazon.aws.accesskey=key
amazon.aws.secretkey=key2

server.port=8080
```

Here is my project structure:
[image]

Here is the relevant class I'm trying to load properties into. I tried the **@PropertySource** annotation with a new properties file, as well as **EnableAutoConfiguration**, but neither are registering the properties file(s).

```
@PropertySource("database.properties")
public class DynamoClientMapper {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String amazonAWSRegion;
```

Here is my App.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class App {

//    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.toString());

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoClientMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\ychen4\Desktop\DiningApplication\target\classes\main\java\com\dining\dao\DynamoClientMapper.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [main.java.com.dining.dao.DynamoClientMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4ba10ad]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: endpoint cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at main.java.com.dining.App.main(App.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [main.java.com.dining.dao.DynamoClientMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4ba10ad]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: endpoint cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: endpoint cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.RuntimeHttpUtils.toUri(RuntimeHttpUtils.java:182) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.util.RuntimeHttpUtils.toUri(RuntimeHttpUtils.java:171) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.toURI(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:238) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.setEndpoint(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:228) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:362) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:337) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
    at main.java.com.dining.dao.DynamoClientMapper.<init>(DynamoClientMapper.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at main.java.com.dining.dao.DynamoClientMapper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4ba10ad.<init>(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

I've tried making another separate database.properties file , but Spring Boot isn't recognizing that either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your configuration class

Comment: I added my stack trace and App.java. Is that what you're looking for? @DoNhuVy

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can make a try to define resources tag in the build section in your pom.xml file. Set path for resource directory where is `application.properties`

```xml
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>resources</directory>
      <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
      <includes>
        <include>application.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30595114/2293534

### Another approach:

If you use spring 3.X version, You can add `@PropertySource("application.properties")`

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    // more configuration ...
}
```

If you use spring 4 version, you add 2 properties file using new annotation called `@PropertySources` that allows you to declare repeated `@PropertySource` annotations:

```java
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("default.properties"),
    @PropertySource("overriding.properties")
})
```

Details is given here in my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659158/2293534

### UPDATE #1:

Replace your `App.java` class with following class

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

//@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

### For `java.io.FileNotFoundException`:

Use the following

```java
@PropertySource(value = "database.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

### UPDATE #2:

I have followed the following steps to run your application. It runs successfully.

1. Go to your project folder where `pom.xml` is exists.
2. You have some errors and warning on `pom.xml`. I have clarified all.
3. Open command prompt and Run `mvn clean`
4. Run `mvn clean install`
5. At last `mvn spring-boot:run`

Then in browser, I run `http://localhost:8080/`

It opens the project successfully. I have also searched other pages also opened successfully.

First page looks like below `http://localhost:8080/`

[image]

All Review pages look like below: `http://localhost:8080/api/reviews`

```json
[
  {"id":1,"userName":"ychennay","reviewText":"This restaurant was terrific!"},{"id":2,"userName":"david","reviewText":"This restaurant
 was okay!"},
  {"id":3,"userName":"ben","reviewText":"This restaurant was
 mediocre!"},
  {"id":4,"userName":"leon","reviewText":"This restaurant
 was awful!"},
  {"id":5,"userName":"lawrence","reviewText":"This
 restaurant was confusing!"}
]
```

### So Replace your `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.diningapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Dining</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
    <spring-version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <dynamodb-local.port>8000</dynamodb-local.port>
    <dynamodb-local.endpoint>http://localhost:${dynamodb-local.port}</dynamodb-local.endpoint>
    <spring-boot-version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
    <aws-sdk-java-version>1.11.124</aws-sdk-java-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>    <!-- For UTF-8 support -->
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>    <!-- For UTF-8 support -->
  </properties>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>          <!-- Used java7 -->
          <target>1.7</target>          <!-- Used java7 -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>dynamodb-local-oregon</id>
      <name>DynamoDB Local Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
      <version>Hopper-SR10</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <!-- <scope>import</scope> -->
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>      <!-- You have missed to add this version -->
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>      <!-- You have missed to add this version -->
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>${aws-sdk-java-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${aws-sdk-java-version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <!-- <scope>import</scope> -->
      <scope>provided</scope>      <!-- changed import to provided -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.38</version>      <!-- You have missed to add this version -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.10</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Errors and solutions:

**Issue #1:**

```bash
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'. @ line 70, column 18
```

**Solution #1:**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
  <version>Hopper-SR10</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <!-- <scope>import</scope> -->
  <scope>provided</scope>  <!-- changed import to provided -->
</dependency>
```

**Issue #2:**

```bash
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar is missing. @ line 73, column 19
```

**Solution #2:**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-boot-version}</version> <!-- You have missed to add this version -->
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Issue #3:**

```bash
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar is missing. @ line 78, column 19
```

**Solution #3:**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-boot-version}</version> <!-- You have missed to add this version -->
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Issue #4:**

```bash
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'. @ line 105, column 18
```

**Solution #4:**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
  <version>${aws-sdk-java-version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <!-- <scope>import</scope> -->
  <scope>provided</scope> <!-- changed import to provided -->
</dependency>
```

**Issue #5:**

```bash
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar is missing. @ line 148, column 19
```

**Solution #5:**

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.38</version> <!-- You have missed to add this version -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but neither solution you mentioned works for me. I receive this error. I clearly have a file called database.properties in my resources folder. `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [main.java.com.dining.App]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: @YuChen Please check the update and let me know the status.

Comment: still no luck. If you'd like, you can clone a copy of the spring boot project from my repo and see for yourself: www.github.com/ychennay/DiningApplication. It's been pretty frustrating.

Comment: @YuChen You have some version missing in pom.xml file. I have resolved all and run successfully. All outputs are attached. So replace your pom.xml and let me know if any issue arises.

Comment: Thanks the second approach works. I'm creating a console application(not web mvc) and it seems like gradle affects the way of packaging resource files.

Comment: Oh man tysm. I have been bashing my head against this wall for a day. It turns out I screwed up the resources in my POM. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Please double-check, that your maven-pom uses this packaging:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

If it is set to `pom` or similar, your IDE might not recognize the "Spring"-nature of your module (happend to me in IntelliJ 2018).

Comment: I've migrated from multi module to single module and this is the thing that caused my application.properties ignored. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BRUH!!!!. I converted an "ordinary" project to a spring boot project and it had pom instead of war or jar and I was on this for DAYS.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of @EnableAutoConfiguration, use @Configuration as below. Also you will need to fix aws region property as its differing in name between prop file and code - [amazon.dynamodb.region vs amazon.aws.region] - this will throw error once it starts picking up property file after below change..

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("database.properties")
public class DynamoClientMapper {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String amazonAWSRegion;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work for me. I get the following error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [main.java.com.dining.App]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: That's obvious expectation that database.properties should be in your classpath. you can put it in resources folder, same location as application.properties unless for some reason you cannot do that and need to keep it in external location then you will have to provide file path in PropertySource as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013760/spring-boot-add-external-property-files

Comment: It is indeed in the same location as application.properties (see my screenshot of my directory tree).

Answer (score 0):

have tried the following approach?

```
@Component
@PropertySource("database.properties")
public class DynamoClientMapper { ...}
```

or

```
 @Service
 @PropertySource("database.properties")
 public class DynamoClientMapper { ...}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get the following error, although there's clearly a database.properties file sitting in the resources folder. `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [main.java.com.dining.App]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

You can use also a fixed path.

*@PropertySource("file:${C:/Development/workspace/Project/resources/}/application.properties")*

Helpful in development process where you want to use different property files.

Answer (score 0):

A problem may also be that you have the dependency of `spring-data-jpa` duplicated in a hierarchy of dependencies, so with this you have 2 sets of different profiles for the environments and when running the app the runner is taking a set of unwanted environments.

```
api("org.springframework.data", "spring-data-jpa", "2.3.4.RELEASE")
```

So I suggest checking the project modules, if there is more than one definition of the dependency download within a hierarchy. Although it is not necessary to delete the one that reappears or duplicates, it is necessary to comment and uncomment them to re-synchronize and for the spring runner to take the desired set of environments.

1. Comment dependency
2. Sync
3. Uncomment dependency
4. Sync
5. Run the app

*Gradle stuff*

GL

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar and I solved it by specifically adding my appliation.properties file to the pom.xml as seen here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

For (very late) upgrades from spring boot 1.x to 2.x:

Use additional directory locations containing application.properties additional to resources/application.properties

```
--spring.config.additional-location=.../
```

instead of spring boot 1.x - which was more flexible with filenames and read both resources/application.properties and spring.config.location:

```
--spring.config.location=file:/...\myapplication.properties
```

Spring boot 2.x still recognices spring.config.location, but it is no longer additional, see
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-location and
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the annotation was in the Dao class, which was downstream of the controller. This class was instantiated with the word **"new"** and consequently did not apply @Values ​​correctly because the new instantiation occurred **outside** the working context of Spring Boot.

I found the solution thanks to a topic similar to this one of which i [attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130486/spring-value-annotation-always-evaluating-as-null/#answer-18403937) the reference.

The solution consists in making the instances downstream of the controller local, **using the @Autowired keywork** in the constructor, and **avoiding using the "new" keyword**. This ensures that the @Values ​​point to the same instance used. I attach an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormController {

    private final FormService formService;
    
    @Autowired
    public FormController(FormService formService) {
        this.formService = formService;
    }
```

The service:

```
@Service
public class FormService implements IFormService {

    private final FormDao formDao;

    @Autowired
    public FormService(FeedbackFormDao formDao) {
        this.formDao = formDao;
    }
```

and finally the DAO (the problem was here in my case):

```
@Repository
public class FormDao {

    @Value("${google.app.name}")
    public String appName;

    @Value("${google.credential.file}")
    public String credentialFile;
```

This was the solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'll tell you what worked for me. I was loading JPA dependency ahead of SpringBoot dependency, just switched that around and it voila. Try to disable/change order of the dependencies in pom.xml .